# get numbers with Jsoup's select()

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have the following html code and i'm trying to extract the date from it.How can i do that with method select() of Jsoup?

```
<span class="lead">Written on</span> 05.01.2013 at 12:16 <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
final String html = "<span class=\"lead\">Written on</span> 05.01.2013 at 12:16 <br />";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for( Element element : doc.select("span.lead") )
{
    // Simple output of the date; 'toString()' gives you the value
    System.out.println(element.nextSibling().toString());
}
```

**Output:**

```
 05.01.2013 at 12:16
```

**Explanation:**

1. With `doc.select("span.lead")` you get the `span`-tag of your Html.
2. You iterate over each `span`-tag (there's only one in this example)
3. With `element.nextSibling()` you get the next Node after the `span` - the textnode you look for

Since there's a leading blank you may use `trim()` to remove it: `element.nextSibling().toString().trim()`